Cellranger count failed at detect chemistry
I'm using Cellranger for alignment on scRNA-seq data but got the following error message:
CalledProcessError: Command '['chunk_reads', '--reads-per-fastq', '5000000', '/path/SC_RNA_COUNTER_CS/SC_RNA_COUNTER/_BASIC_SC_RNA_COUNTER/CHUNK_READS/fork0/chnk0-u1b14459fe6/files/', 'fastq_chunk', '--martian-args', 'chunk_args.json', '--compress', 'lz4']' returned non-zero exit status 101

I performed md5sum on all fastq files and received OK.
May I ask what can be reason for this error and how can I detect it and fix it?
Thanks for any help.

"I performed md5sum on all fastq files and received OK" Could you explain this please? OK in this context only make sense if you are comparing the hashes to a previous run, it doesn't tell us anything about the files other than that they are identical to some other files. What exactly did you compare to? What are your input files? Are they compressed? How? If with gzip, what does gzip -t YOUR_FILE && echo OK || echo BAD return?

This is not a full error message; it is an indication that there was an error. Does the program provide any additional information beyond this message you have seen?
